# Can't seem to access values in object in javascript using dot or array notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I get data from an external api (omdbapi) and the exact data looks like follows with a title of Star:

```
{"Search":[{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope","Year":"1977","imdbID":"tt0076759","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzVlY2MwMjktM2E4OS00Y2Y3LWE3ZjctYzhkZGM3YzA1ZWM2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back","Year":"1980","imdbID":"tt0080684","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYmU1NDRjNDgtMzhiMi00NjZmLTg5NGItZDNiZjU5NTU4OTE0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi","Year":"1983","imdbID":"tt0086190","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOWZlMjFiYzgtMTUzNC00Y2IzLTk1NTMtZmNhMTczNTk0ODk1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens","Year":"2015","imdbID":"tt2488496","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTAzODEzNDAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU1MTgzNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace","Year":"1999","imdbID":"tt0120915","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTRhNjcwNWQtMGJmMi00NmQyLWE2YzItODVmMTdjNWI0ZDA2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith","Year":"2005","imdbID":"tt0121766","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTc4MTc3NTQ5OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTg0NjI4NA@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones","Year":"2002","imdbID":"tt0121765","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDAzM2M0Y2UtZjRmZi00MzVlLTg4MjEtOTE3NzU5ZDVlMTU5XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDUyOTg3Njg@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Trek","Year":"2009","imdbID":"tt0796366","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjE5NDQ5OTE4Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTE3NDIzMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode VIII - The Last Jedi","Year":"2017","imdbID":"tt2527336","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjQ1MzcxNjg4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzgwMjY4MzI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Rogue One: A Star Wars Story","Year":"2016","imdbID":"tt3748528","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjEwMzMxODIzOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzg3OTAzMDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"}],"totalResults":"2895","Response":"True"}
```

I'm doing it in react native and this object called movies is being passed as props. The code is as follows:

```
const MoviesList = props => {

    return 
    <Text>
        {props.movies.Search.forEach((movie) => {
            movie.Title
        })}
    </Text>
}
```

All I get is `undefined` and none of the data is rendered.

Comment: Create a snippet to show the problem.

Comment: Can you add the part of your code that uses this object?

Comment: I ran the code as provided above and it works fine

Comment: Is the obj available in your code at that moment, or does `obj` get overwritten by another value?

Comment: I am guessing, that the problem is in the context in which you are trying to access this code. You need to provide us with this context. When is the obj accessed?

Comment: I have added a demo. your code seems to work fine. Please update it, if something is missing.

Comment: @KostasX I already did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `forEach` when you're trying to render child elements/components since forEach does not actually return anything new it simply loops through an existing collection. You can make changes to the items as they are looped through but a new collection is not created or returned.

You should use `map` instead.

I am not sure what `Text` is, like if it's your own component or from a library but if it's your own component and you want to render the titles within that component, you should wrap your loop within the `<Text>` component but rather pass the title to `<Text>`.

See below in **MoviesList.js**

```
<div>

  {props.movies.Search.map((movie) => {
    return <Text title={movie.Title}/>
  })}

</div>
```

I made a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-d2t2v) for the full code.

**EDIT**

If the response from the API is coming back as a string instead of an object, you can use `JSON.parse(YOUR_RESULTS)` to convert your string into an object.

To see if the results are in fact a string, you can perform `YOUR_RESULTS.split("")` and see if an array is returned. You can also do `console.log(typeof YOUR_RESULTS)`. If it is in fact a string, `"string"` will be logged in the console.

Comment: Thank you. Problem is, props.movies.Search seems to be undefined and when I try to do map every single character gets rendered individually, even those outside of search

Comment: What does `console.log(props.movies)` log? If it is undefined then you are not passing your props correctly. Wherever you're rendering your `MovieList` component needs to have access to the object. If you see the codesandbox I provided the props are passed and the values are rendered correctly.

Comment: It returns the full movie list with everithing including Search and Response. When I try to access Search though it returns undefined

Comment: Can you share what the response looks like? I am assuming `Search` would correspond to an input search. When I tried the API online it only showed options to search by title or id.

Comment: The exact url I used for this example is: http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=3e3e9b41&s=Star by using s instead of t you can get variuos results which is my objective

Comment: I think I got it the data I get through fetch is returnned as a string not as an object. How can I mak eit be returned as an object? Would it work getting it as a json object?

Comment: If you think it is a string you can use `JSON.parse(YOUR_RESULTS)` and this should parse your string into an object. To test if it's a string, you can do `YOUR_RESULTS.split("")` and see if it turns `YOUR_RESULTS` into an array.

Comment: OMG IT WORKS THANK YOU SO MUCH HAVE A NICE DAY

Comment: Of course. Feel free the accept the answer and good luck with your project.